# Getting error "invalid uri" when using http://localhost

Tags: c#, surveymonkey

I'm working with my first api here and I'm trying to get through the Oauth authorization so i can start working with the api. When trying to get the short life access key with the following code surveymonkey is telling me I have an invalid uri. The api key and username are replaced with dummies

```
string url = "https://api.surveymonkey.net/oauth/authorize";
string api_key = "api_key=sdwertyujgfv3f24qqa4kfyd";
string client_id = "client_id=XXX";
string redirect_uri="redirect_uri=http://localhost";
url = url + "?" + redirect_uri +"&" + client_id + "&" + api_key;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```

What is the uri and how do i use is in this situation.

Comment: have you checked here https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/guide_oauth

Comment: yeah I'm not too familiar with python and i didnt see anything in that guide that would help with the problem I'm having.

Comment: In this link https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/authentication they mention this library http://dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: You haven't URL-encoded your `redirect_uri` parameter. Try `"redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost"` instead.

Comment: Make sure your redirect_uri matches the url you have on your application on Mashery.

Answer (score 0):

You can not bitly a `localhost` link. You could try with `127.0.0.1` instead just to get it to work. But ultimately once the app is deployed it's hostname will not be localhost so it will work if that was the only obstacle.